# 1286 - Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5

I am trying to use roundcube and it recently just broke. I don't know if this is due to a MySQL update that happened recently or not but in phpMyAdmin I get the following error if I try and view a table:

```
1286 - Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'
```

and

```
mysql> SHOW ENGINES;
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| MRG_MYISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM             | DEFAULT | MyISAM storage engine                                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE          | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| FEDERATED          | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| ARCHIVE            | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
local-infile=0
symbolic-links=0
skip-networking
max_connections = 500
max_user_connections = 20
key_buffer = 512M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
join_buffer_size = 64M
read_buffer_size = 12M
sort_buffer_size = 12M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 12M
table_cache = 2048
thread_cache_size = 16K
wait_timeout = 30
connect_timeout = 15
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
max_allowed_packet = 64M
max_connect_errors = 10
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size = 64M
query_cache_type = 1
low_priority_updates=1
concurrent_insert=ALWAYS
log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log
tmpdir=/home/mysqltmp
myisam_repair_threads=4
[mysqld_safe]
open_files_limit = 8192
log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 512M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 64M
sort_buffer = 64M
read_buffer = 16M
write_buffer = 16M
```

Ideas as to how to fix? It used to work just fine.

Comment: Check what mysql error log (/var/log/mysql/error.log) says on startup.

Answer (score 6):

## OBSERVATIONS

- I see there is nothing Innodb-related in the `my.cnf`.
- Look for Innodb-related error messages expressing why mysqld failed to start in the error log.

My first guess would be look at the `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` in `/var/lib/mysql`.

If they have been set to size different from the default, that probably will prevent mysqld's startup. The default for [innodb_log_file_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size) is 5M.

## SUGGESTION #1

If RoundCube's installation overwrote the `my.cnf`, see if you have a physical backup of the previous `my.cnf`. Put that back in place and run

```
service mysql start
```

## SUGGESTION #2

Take the filesize of `ib_logfile0` and divide by 1048576. Let's say it is 12M.

Put that in `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
innodb_log_file_size = 12M
```

then run

```
service mysql start
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 2):

Just delete `ib_logfileX` files and restart mysql service.

You changed the `innodb-log-file-size` var to size more bigger than already set it in your mysql daemon.

Comment: I've edited your post. Please use punctuation and full words next time. "u" is not a word ;)

Answer (score 1):

Petre already wrote it, but perhaps to clarify:

It seems that the InnoDB Engine is not loaded when MySQL cannot write to the temp directory (usually /tmp). This might be caused by either a full temp partition, or incorrect permissions on the temp directory.

As Petre has mentioned `chmod 1777 /tmp` should resolve this issue. Don't forget to restart MySQL afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303133/unknown-table-engine-innodb

Some of the things that are mentioned in the article:
1. Deleting innodb log files.
2. Changing innodb_buffer_pool_size to lower then 2G

Answer (score 0):

When you have disable innodb, dont' forget to remove all innodb-related tables from Dbs. For example "mysql" database has 5 of them:

```
root@ustimen.co$ mysql mysql -e 'show table status' | grep Unknown | awk '{print $1}'
innodb_index_stats
innodb_table_stats
slave_master_info
slave_relay_log_info
slave_worker_info
```

Answer (score 0):

I use roundcube, apache2, mysql, dovecot, postfix.

After a harddisk crash and reinstall of the same system on a new HDD I cannot connect to the mail server by web application (roundcube). The message was "Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'".

After about 2 weeks of searching the configuration fault without results and by a miracle, today, I saw that some of the linux components cannot write in /tmp.

That's all that I did ... put `chmod 1777 /tmp` ...
Now it's running ok!

Good luck!